# Como Saber qual versão do ionic esta sendo usada no meu projeto

Tags: ionic

Estou trabalhando em um projeto em ionic na minha empresa, mas eu não sei qual versão ele foi feito, e quem fez nao trabalha mais na empresa, como faço para descobrir em qual versão ele foi criado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode rodar o comando `ionic info` na pasta do projeto

A saída vai ser algo como:

> ```
> C:\User\ProjetoIonic> ionic info
> Cordova CLI: X.X.X
> Ionic Version: X.X.X
> Ionic CLI Version: X.X.X
> Ionic App Lib Version: X.X.X
> OS: Versão do sistema
> Node Version: vX.X.X
> ```

Se a versão do ionic for muito antiga, talvez apareça que "info não é uma tarefa válida", então é possível usar o comando `ionic lib`

A saída vai ser algo como:

> ```
> C:\User\ProjetoIonic>  ionic lib
> Local Ionic version: X.X.X 
> Latest Ionic version: X.X.X
> * Local version up to date
> ```

Comment: Isso mesmo, basta o comando ionic info